# video player in Grails

Tags: grails, video

I'm looking for a way to add a video player into my grails app.
I cannot find any other than flash i would prefer HTML

Is there a way i can embed a HTML5 video played into my app

any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the HTML5 `<video>` tag. It's non-flash and will work in modern browsers. If you need to support older browsers, your only real option is via a plugin like Flash or Silverlight, unfortunately.